# Undefined when retrieving text from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
<tr><td id="name">TEXT 1</td> 
<td><input type="button" class="button_add" value="Add" ></td></tr>
<tr><td id="name">TEXT 2</td> 
<td><input type="button" class="button_add" value="Add" ></td></tr>
```

I would to click on the button to read the value of the current element td. For eg.: "This is your text: TEXT1"-

My code in jQuery is :

```
$('.button_add').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("#name").html();
    alert('This is your text' + name);
});
```

But when I click on the button I get the following error:

> TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

And it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` value twice in an html document.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do when the user clicks on `.button_add`. But I can say that you're having an error because you're trying to get an attribute `name` from the input (which you haven't set). Besides, you should do something like `$(this).attr('name')` (withouth the `#` sign). You should really [take some time to learn jQuery](http://www.codecademy.com/pt/tracks/jquery).

Answer (score 3):

ID of an element must be unique, so use `name` as a class instead of as ID.

Since you need the value of td in the same tr, use .closest to find the `tr` then use the class selector to find the `td`

```js
$('.button_add').click(function() {
  var name = $(this).closest("tr").find('td.name').html();
  //or since the target td is the previous sibling of the button's parent element
  //  var name = $(this).parent().prev().html();

  alert('This is your text' + name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">TEXT 1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="button_add" value="Add">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">TEXT 2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="button_add" value="Add">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: would use `.parent()` instead of `.closest()` though

Comment: @Loïc yes... already added it as an suggestion... then need to use `.prev()`